# SQL Server equivalent for Firebird SUSPEND

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, firebird, firebird2.5

I have a stored procedure from a Firebird database which calls SUSPEND several times through the procedure.  I am not the writer of this procedure, nor am I very skilled at Firebird syntax, however the [Firebird docs](http://www.janus-software.com/fbmanual/manual.php?book=PSQL&topic=104) state the following:

> Use SUSPEND to return a row of data from a procedure to its caller.

I am using software that converts the procedure to its SQL Server equivalent, however the only portion that was not converted is the SUSPEND statement.  So, I've commented it out to get the procedure created in SQL Server, but now when I execute it I get no data back.  In the converted SQL Server version, the SUSPEND occurs within the cursor loop.  In the Firebird version, it occurs in the for loop.

I am executing the procedure like so...

```
EXEC MY_CONVERTED_FB_PROCEDURE ARG1,ARG2,ARG3, etc...
```

In Firebird, I usually do

`SELECT * FROM MY_FB_PROCEDURE (ARG1,ARG2,ARG3,...)`

which gives me back the result set.

My question is, does anyone have a custom function they could share, or a code snippet, that I can add in place of the SUSPEND statement so that SQL Server will perform the same process for the procedure as Firebird does?

**Full converted SQL Server procedure (with SUSPEND commented out)**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ACCIDENT_SUMMARY_V2 
@IN_LOGINID INT,
    @IN_CUSTID VARCHAR(6),
    @IN_CUSTDIV VARCHAR(6),
    @IN_UNIT VARCHAR(6),
    @STARTDATE DATE,
    @ENDDATE DATE,
    @MONTHLY_BREAKDOWN_FLAG CHAR(1),
    @IN_GROUPBY VARCHAR(20)

AS
begin

   declare @ONE_ACCT_REF INT
   declare @TOT_ACCIDENT_COUNT INT
   declare @NUM_MONTHS FLOAT
   declare @YR_START VARCHAR(4)
   declare @YR_END VARCHAR(4)
   declare @SAV_MMM_YYYY VARCHAR(15)
   declare @SAV_GROUPBY VARCHAR(20)
   declare @SAV_ACCIDENT_COUNT INT
   DECLARE @YYYY_MM INT
   DECLARE @MMM_YYYY VARCHAR(15)
   DECLARE @GROUPBY VARCHAR(80)
   DECLARE @SUBTOTAL_FLAG CHAR(1)
   DECLARE @EXPENSE_MONTH DATE
   DECLARE @MILES_DRIVEN INT
   DECLARE @CUSTDIV VARCHAR(6)
   DECLARE @UNIT VARCHAR(6)
   DECLARE @ACCT_REF INT
   DECLARE @CURRENT_MMM_YYYY VARCHAR(15)
   DECLARE @CURRENT_YYYY_MM VARCHAR(15)
   DECLARE @BILLTOTAL NUMERIC(15,2)
   DECLARE @TOT_EXP_GLASS NUMERIC(15,2)
   DECLARE @TOT_EXP_SUBROGATE NUMERIC(15,2)
   DECLARE @TOT_EXP_BODYWORK NUMERIC(15,2)
   DECLARE @TOT_EXP_RENT NUMERIC(15,2)
   DECLARE @TOT_EXP_SURCHARGE NUMERIC(15,2)
   DECLARE @TOT_EXP_TAXES NUMERIC(15,2)
   DECLARE @TOT_EXP_TOW NUMERIC(15,2)
   DECLARE @ACCIDENT_COUNT INT
   DECLARE @DRIVER_AT_FAULT_COUNT INT
   DECLARE @DRY_ROAD_COUNT INT
   DECLARE @NOTDRY_ROAD_COUNT INT
   DECLARE @CLASS_REAREND_COUNT INT
   DECLARE @CLASS_PARKING_COUNT INT
   DECLARE @CLASS_PARKED_COUNT INT
   DECLARE @SWV_cursor_var1 CURSOR
   SET @DRIVER_AT_FAULT_COUNT = 0
   SET @ACCIDENT_COUNT = 0
   SET @DRY_ROAD_COUNT  = 0
   SET @NOTDRY_ROAD_COUNT = 0
   SET @TOT_ACCIDENT_COUNT = 0

   SET @CURRENT_YYYY_MM = null
   if ((@IN_GROUPBY is null OR  @IN_GROUPBY = ''))
      SET @IN_GROUPBY = 'nogroup'


   if ((@IN_UNIT is not null AND  @IN_UNIT <> ''))
      select @ONE_ACCT_REF = acct_id from custacct ca
      where ca.custID = @IN_CUSTID
      and ca.unit = @IN_UNIT
ELSE
   SET @ONE_ACCT_REF = null

   SET @SWV_cursor_var1 = CURSOR  FOR (** SELECT STATEMENT HERE **)

   OPEN @SWV_cursor_var1

   FETCH NEXT FROM @SWV_cursor_var1 INTO @YYYY_MM,@MMM_YYYY,@GROUPBY,@BILLTOTAL,@TOT_EXP_GLASS,@TOT_EXP_SUBROGATE,
   @TOT_EXP_BODYWORK,@TOT_EXP_RENT,@TOT_EXP_TOW,@TOT_EXP_SURCHARGE,@TOT_EXP_TAXES,
   @DRIVER_AT_FAULT_COUNT,@DRY_ROAD_COUNT,@NOTDRY_ROAD_COUNT, 
   @CLASS_REAREND_COUNT,@CLASS_PARKING_COUNT,@CLASS_PARKED_COUNT,@ACCIDENT_COUNT

   while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
   begin
      if ((@MONTHLY_BREAKDOWN_FLAG = 'T') and (@YYYY_MM <>  @CURRENT_YYYY_MM) and ((@CURRENT_YYYY_MM is not null AND  @CURRENT_YYYY_MM <> ''))
      and @IN_GROUPBY <> 'nogroup')
      begin
         SET @SAV_MMM_YYYY      = @MMM_YYYY
         SET @SAV_GROUPBY       = @GROUPBY
         SET @SAV_ACCIDENT_COUNT      = @ACCIDENT_COUNT

          --miles_driven  = :tot_miles_driven;
         SET @ACCIDENT_COUNT = @TOT_ACCIDENT_COUNT
         SET @SUBTOTAL_FLAG = 'T'
         SET @GROUPBY = 'Subtotal'
         SET @MMM_YYYY = @CURRENT_MMM_YYYY
         --suspend
         SET @MMM_YYYY      = @SAV_MMM_YYYY
         SET @GROUPBY       = @SAV_GROUPBY
         SET @ACCIDENT_COUNT = @SAV_ACCIDENT_COUNT
      end
      SET @CURRENT_YYYY_MM = @YYYY_MM
      SET @CURRENT_MMM_YYYY = @MMM_YYYY
      SET @SUBTOTAL_FLAG = 'F'

       --tot_miles_driven  = :tot_miles_driven + :miles_driven;
      SET @TOT_ACCIDENT_COUNT = @TOT_ACCIDENT_COUNT+@ACCIDENT_COUNT
      SET @YR_START = year(@STARTDATE)
      SET @YR_END = year(@ENDDATE)
      SET @YR_START = SUBSTRING(@YR_START,3,4)
      SET @YR_END = SUBSTRING(@YR_END,3,4)
      --suspend
      FETCH NEXT FROM @SWV_cursor_var1 INTO @YYYY_MM,@MMM_YYYY,@GROUPBY,@BILLTOTAL,@TOT_EXP_GLASS,@TOT_EXP_SUBROGATE,
      @TOT_EXP_BODYWORK,@TOT_EXP_RENT,@TOT_EXP_TOW,@TOT_EXP_SURCHARGE,@TOT_EXP_TAXES,
      @DRIVER_AT_FAULT_COUNT,@DRY_ROAD_COUNT,@NOTDRY_ROAD_COUNT, 
      @CLASS_REAREND_COUNT,@CLASS_PARKING_COUNT,@CLASS_PARKED_COUNT,@ACCIDENT_COUNT
   end
   CLOSE @SWV_cursor_var1

         -- miles_driven  = :tot_miles_driven;
   if ((@MONTHLY_BREAKDOWN_FLAG = 'T') and ((@CURRENT_YYYY_MM is not null AND  @CURRENT_YYYY_MM <> '')) and (@IN_GROUPBY <> 'nogroup'))
   begin
      SET @SUBTOTAL_FLAG = 'T'
      SET @GROUPBY = 'Subtotal'
      --suspend
   end
   RETURN
END
```

Comment: You should consider trashing this code entirely and writing this as single set based operation instead of RBAR (row by agonizing row) over a cursor.

Comment: @SeanLange - assuming that's not an option for me, is it possible to perform the same thing the Firebird SUSPEND would be doing, but in this SQL Server version?

Comment: I don't know what suspend does in Firebird. Is that a wait command?

Comment: @SeanLange - link in my question to the official docs on it, but it basically returns the current row of data back to the caller from the stored proc.

Comment: look into RETURN perhaps?

Comment: @SeanLange `SUSPEND` in Firebird outputs a row and waits for that row to be fetched by the client, and then proceeds with the rest of stored procedure. If the 'suspended' row is never fetched (and the statement/cursor closed by the client), then any changes up to the previous suspend are undone. It is not equivalent to `return`, as that ends execution of a stored procedure.

Comment: The best solution is probably as suggested by Sean, transform it to a select that outputs the result, otherwise consider inserting into a temporary table, and select from that temporary table at the end of the stored procedure, although is probably a bit of a kludge, and uglier than Sean's suggestion.

Comment: It sounds like perhaps this is similar to a transaction and the suspend would be the rollback? Since this entire looping construct is nothing more than a total why not simply change this whole complicated and slow process to select sum(column1), sum(column2) etc??

Comment: @SeanLange In Firebird suspend outputs the current values assigned to the 'return columns' (like OUT parameters, but then you can have multiple rows). An equivalent would probably require some use of window functions to produce running totals. A suspend is a combination of 'output row' and a savepoint. Contrary to SQL Server, Firebird cannot produce multiple result sets, and the columns of the single result set need to be declared in advance.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel further evidence that abandoning looping is appropriate here. :)

Comment: @SeanLange I agree, the only thing you'd lose is the savepoint-like behavior of suspend, and that isn't used here anyway. And you gain a lot more readable code. Even in Firebird it would be better to transform this to a `for select ... into ... `-loop with a suspend instead of this (although I haven't looked too closely at all the data mangling going on in the example).

Comment: After consulting with a colleague, it appears this Firebird stored proc will actually be a Function in SQL Server.  I need to add a "returns TABLE(...)" statement and then perform inserts into that table where necessary.  Thank you to all for the information and advice!!!!

Comment: After all the good reasons not to mimic the Firebird's stored procedure logic you still need SUSPEND functionality, i'd say that the best way to achieve this would be to use a TEMP table idenitical to the output you will be returning and where the SUSPEND was you do an INSERT INTO this TEMP TABLE... At the very end, you do a Select * from TEMP TABLE to return the results.